# Flash Barcode Reader

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm interested to write a barcode scanner with flash which would work for any
platform that has built-in camera and while scanning which automatically uses the camera for barcode reading does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this or have a guide for this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you done any research?

This post looks promising:

http://www.remotesynthesis.com/post.cfm/adding-a-qr-code-reader-in-flex-on-android

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the following:
[http://code.google.com/p/flexbars/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fexamples%253Fstate%253Dclosed](http://code.google.com/p/flexbars/source/browse/#svn/trunk/examples%253Fstate%253Dclosed)